# Concatenate control name in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I don't know how to say this, I have 3 datagridview control (named `datagridview1`, `datagridview2` & `datagridview3`). My question is can I concatenate the name of those control?

I mean is there a way that I can call it like this: `datagridview(n) or datagridview + n`

I'm using winforms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you needing to do this? if your building controls dynamically, I cans ee the point, otherwise like Tim mentionedm use readable names.

Comment: Use meaningful names that are related to their purpose.

Comment: I have 3 tabpage, and each tabpage contains a datagridview, I want to call the datagridview in the current tabpage and I don't want to call the name of those datagridview everytime I change the tabpage.

Comment: You could set the Tag property of the TabPage to a DatagridView reference. Then you might do: 
tabControl.TabChanged +=  {
    var grid =  tabControl.SelectedTabPage.Tag as DataGridView;
    
    grid.DoSomething();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to find the control with a dynamic name?

Something like this perhaps:

```
Control match = ParentControl.Controls["datagridview" + n];
```

So if for example all your data grid are in a single panel called "MyPanel", then you can do this:

```
DataGridView match = MyPanel.Controls["datagridview" + n] as DataGridView;
```

---

If however, your data grids do not all belong to the same parent control, then you can find them using the [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) method:

```
DataGridView match = this.Controls.Find("datagridview" + n, true)[0] as DataGridView;
```

NOTE: The Controls.Find method returns an array, so you need to select the first element (assuming your control name is unique), it may also be worth checking if the array has any values before trying to access the first element too.

---

If you want to wrap that in a function, you can do this:

```
public DataGridView GetDataGridViewForTabNumber(int n){
    Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find("datagridview" + n, true);
    if(matches.length == 0) 
        return null;
    return matches[0] as DataGridView;
}
```

and call it like so:

```
DataGridView dgv = GetDataGridViewForTabNumber(1);//gets datagridview1
```

---

NOTE: This is a perfectly valid method if you are creating DataGridView controls dynamically at run time. If however, you are creating them in the designer then, like Tim said, you should give them a more meaningful name and reference them directly.

Comment: I am creating them in designer, I want my code to be simple,. I have 3 tabpage and each tabpage contains a datagridview, so I have a variable n which value is based on the current tabpage, so when the tabpage changed, the variable value will also change, and I want to use that variable like datagridview + n. Is is possible?

Comment: @user2061086: Simple code? Then just use the name of the control to access it, `datagridview1.CallSomething();`

Comment: @user2061086: yes that is possible, my code explains that exactly

Comment: @user2061086: Of course it did :P Don't forget, you can thank me by accepting/upvoting my answer. This way you will improve your own reputation which will help improve the answers you get next time you are stuck in a jam. Remember, SO is a community where we all like to help each other.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote it up . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> DataGridView dg = (DataGridView)this.Controls.Find("datagridview"+**n.ToString()**, true);